# Showing math symbols in mfc applications

Tags: c++, visual-studio, math, mfc

I am going to create a MFC form in order to show mathematical expression I need to set a text to some symbols such as Theta(**θ**). How can set a text of text-box to a string which contains these kinds of symbols.

Comment: consider looking into using sdl. It has a bunch of stuff for printing text across platforms, and it works with c/c++. If you can't find the symbols you are looking for, then you can make them using something like openGL.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are defining a dialog, you can set the font used - I usually use Arial Unicode MS... this will let  you show any Greek symbol - or Japanse one for that matter

Comment: I set the font of dialog and use Unicode chars in its name. But in debug time the Unicode chars changed to ? in dialog?!?

Comment: Are you compiling in ANSI or UNICODE? You need to set it to be Unicode and use _T("data") in your code